# Algorithm to get maximum value of tuples from two sets

Tags: algorithms

I have two sets *A* and *B*. Each tuple from *A x B* has a score associated to it.
E.g.:

- **I:** (A1, B1) -> 5
- **II:** (A1, B2) -> 7
- **III:** (A2, B1) -> 3
- **IV:** (A2, B2) -> 4

I now want to get the combination of tuples that has the highest value. However, every item can only be used once.
So in this case the possible combinations would be:

- (I, IV): 5 + 4 = 9
- (II, III): 7 + 3 = 10
  So in this case the highest achievable score when only using each item once would be 20.

*A* and *B* are distinct and possibly have a different size.

Can anyone think of a smarter way than just brute forcing this? What's a similar problem I can take a look at?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for a [maximum-weight matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Maximum-weight_matching) in a bipartite graph. You could model it like this:

- **Nodes**: $A \cup B$
- **Edges**: all combinations in $a, b \in A \times B$ with their respective weights $\mu(a,b)$

This graph will be bipartite, and the *combination of tuples* you were refering to would be a matching in that graph. A *matching* refers to a set of edges in the graph where no two edges have a common adjacent node. Since you didn't state whether there should be exactly two tuples or not, this matching could either be capped at 2 or get larger and become maximal.

Since you want to get a combination that yields the highest value (in our case the largest total weight), we need a maximum-weight matching – which we'll call $M$. *Maximum-weight* is just another way to say that we can't find a different matching $M'$ where $\sum_{e \in M} \mu(e) \le \sum_{e \in M} \mu(e)$.

As for it's complexity, our graph has $O(n)$ nodes, where $n$ is the larger of $\lvert A \rvert$ and $\lvert B \rvert$. Further, we have $O(n^2)$ Edges. You can have a look on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) to read about possible solutions. The reference algorithm would run in $O(n^3)$ in our case, which is better than brute forcing by a factor of $n$. NetworkX also seems to [implement](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.matching.max_weight_matching.html#networkx.algorithms.matching.max_weight_matching) an algorithm with this complexity.

Comment: Wow! we both posted almost the same answer at the same time! You have my respects for posting 3 minutes earlier :) Take my upvote

Comment: Thanks, that is in fact the same answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Lets define the following bipartite graph:

The nodes in the first group, will be the elements from $A$, and the nodes in the second group will be the elements from $B$.

Add an edge between every element $a\in A$ to every element $b\in B$, and put a weight on that edge equal to the value of $(a,b)$.

Now, each tuple will correspond to a particular edge in the graph, and hence any matching (or independent set) will be a valid "set of tuples" (since no item is used twice).

Now your question boils down to finding a maximal matching, which can [be solved quickly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem)